# update CGridView with ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii, cgridview

I have a grid using CGridView and when ever I am trying to update it I get this error.  trying a way to resolve this for a long and still couldn't get it worked. I am not sure what am I missing.

following is what I am using to force the grid to refresh when a button click occurs.

```
$('#sessions .refreshdata').live('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.fn.yiiGridView.update('sessions-grid');
}
);
```

The error comes is,

```
TypeError: settings is undefined

$grid.addClass(settings.loadingClass);
```

I have no idea from where this triggers.

[image]

**EDIT 1,**

I tried with setting process output true and then it worked but it messed with my UI and other needed scripts in the same page.

```
$this->getController()->renderPartial('sessionGrid', $params, false, true);
```

I started getting yii's default gridview and its styles. confused why this happens.

Sorting also doesn't work in the same grid.  When I click on a sorting link of a column name, it refresh the page and takes me to another page. so Ajax is completely not working in this case.

**EDIT 2,**

Below way also dint work  as suggested in ANSWER 1

```
console.log('came in');
e.preventDefault();
$.fn.yiiGridView({ 'ajaxUpdate':['sessions-grid'] }); 
console.log('came out');
```

how can I force this grid to refresh or update ?

**EDIT 3,**

When I use the normal way,  an error comes up from jquery.yiigridview.js. settings is undefined - Line 203.. **$grid.addClass(settings.loadingClass);**

```
return this.each(function () {
var $form,
$grid = $(this),
id = $grid.attr('id'),
settings = gridSettings[id];
$grid.addClass(settings.loadingClass);
```

EDIT 4, I am here below copying the cgridview code and action.

```
<?php TK::registerCssFile('grid');?>
<div id="sessions">
<h4><?php echo Yii::t('activity', (isset($model->activity->name) ? $model->activity->name . ' Sessions'  : 'Sessions')) ?></h4>
<?php $this->beginContent('application.views.templates.form', array('options'=>array('id'=>'sessions-form'))); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::hiddenField('activities_id', $model->activities_id); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::hiddenField('source', $source); ?>
<?php
$this->widget('application.components.SGridView', array(
   'id'=>'sessions-grid',
   'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
   'filter'=>$model,
   'emptyText'=>(!empty($model->activities_id)) ? 'No results found.' : 'Please select activity from top grid.',
   'showNew'=>(!empty($model->activities_id) &&  Yii::app()->user->checkAccess("piActivitySessionsCreate") && $model->activity->source === 'iJOB') ? true : false,
   'newButtonCss'=>'new dialog-link-session',
   'createUrl'=>Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("/activities/default/sessionCreate", array("activities_id"=>$model->activities_id)),
   //'showExport'=>true,
   'columns'=>array(
      /*
      array('type'=>'raw',
         'value'=>'CHtml::hiddenField("ActivitySession[$data->id]", false, array(\'value\'=>$data->id))',
         'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:0%;'),
         'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:0%;')),
      */      
      array('name'=>'site_id',
         //'value'=>'CHtml::link($data->sites->code, "#", array("title"=>$data->sites->name))',
         //'value'=>'CHtml::label($data->sites->code, null, array("title"=>$data->sites->name))',
         'value'=>'$data->sites!=null ? CHtml::tag("div", array("title"=>$data->sites->name), $data->sites->code) : ""',
         'type'=>'raw',
         'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:16%;'),
         'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:16%;')),
      array('name'=>'location',
         'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:30%;'),
         'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:30%;')),
      array('name'=>'start_time',
         'value'=>'Yii::app()->dateFormatter->formatDateTime($data->start_time, "medium", "short")',
         'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:15%;'),
         'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:15%;')),
      array('name'=>'end_time',
         'value'=>'Yii::app()->dateFormatter->formatDateTime($data->end_time, "medium", "short")',
         'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:15%;'),
         'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:15%;')),
      /*
      array('name'=>'max_positions',
         'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:6%;'),
         'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:6%;')),
      */
      array('name'=>'closed',
         'value'=>'$data->closed == "1" ? Yii::t("activity", "Yes") : Yii::t("activity", "No")',
         'filter'=>array("0"=>Yii::t("activity", "No"), "1"=>Yii::t("activity", "Yes")),
         'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:6%;text-align:left;'),
         'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:6%;')),
      array('name'=>'registered',
         'type'=>'raw',
         'value'=>'$data->registeredCount . \'/\' . $data->max_positions',
         'filter'=>false,
         'sortable'=>true,
         'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:8%;text-align:right;padding-right:15px'),
         'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:8%;')),
      array('class'=>'CButtonColumn',
         'template'=>'{users} {view} {update} {delete}',
         'header'=>Yii::t("activity","Actions"),
         'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:10%;'),
         'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:10%;'),
         'buttons'=>array(
            'users'=>array(
               'visible'=>'(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess("piActivityJobseekerRead") || Yii::app()->user->checkAccess("piActivityJobseekerUpdate")) ? true : false',
               'url'=>'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("/activities/participants/index", array("session_id"=>$data->id))',
               'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/base/users.png',               
               'options'=>array(
                  //'class'=>'users dialog-link-session',
                  'title'=>Yii::t('activity', 'Participants'),
               ),
            ),
            'view'=>array(
               'visible'=>'(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess("piActivitySessionsRead") && 
                  !Yii::app()->user->checkAccess("piActivitySessionsUpdate") && $data->activity->source === "iJOB") ||
                  ($data->activity->source === "ESS") ? true : false',
               'url'=>'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("/activities/default/sessionView", array("id"=>$data->id))',
               'options'=>array('class'=>'view dialog-link-session'),
            ),
            'update'=>array(
               'visible'=>'(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess("piActivitySessionsUpdate") && $data->activity->source === "iJOB") ? true : false',
               'url'=>'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("/activities/default/sessionUpdate", array("id"=>$data->id))',
               'options'=>array('class'=>'update dialog-link-session'),
            ),
            'delete'=>array(
               'visible'=>'(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess("piActivitySessionsDelete") && $data->activity->source === "iJOB") ? true : false',
               'url'=>'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("/activities/default/sessionDelete", array("id"=>$data->id))',
               'options'=>array('class'=>'delete dialog-link-session'),
            ),
         ),
      ),
      array('type'=>'raw',
         'value'=>'$data->registeredCount',
         'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:none;'),
         'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:none;'),
      ),
   ),
));
?>
<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
.grid-view-body
{
    height: 170px;
}
</style>
```

AND in action....

```
public function run()
   {
      Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['*.js'] = false;
      $activities_id = (TK::get('activities_id') ? TK::get('activities_id') : (TK::post('activities_id') ? TK::post('activities_id') : 0));
      $source = (TK::get('source') ? TK::get('source') : (TK::post('source') ? TK::post('source') : 'iJOB'));
      
      if ($activities_id === null)
        throw new CHttpException(500, Yii::t('activity', 'The requested activity does not exist.'));
      
      $model = new ActivitySession('search');
      $model->unsetAttributes();
      $model->activities_id = $activities_id;
      $model->closed = null;     
      
      if (isset($_GET['ActivitySession']))
         $model->attributes = $_GET['ActivitySession'];
         
      $params = array('model'=>$model, 'source'=>$source);
      
      if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
         $this->getController()->renderPartial('sessionGrid', $params, false, true);
      else
         $this->getController()->renderPartial('sessionGrid', $params, false, true);
   }
```

Then the I have the gridview as below along with the refresh button...

[image]

After making porcessedOutput = true,  the refreshed start working but every time it increases by one.. so refresh now occurs multiple time.. below is a capture of it happened 3 times now. [image]

How can I stop this refreshing happening multiple time is my question.

Comment: This problem happens in all browsers?

Comment: @DanielVaquero yeah it happens in all and grid is not updating with  button click. pls check the edited section of this question above.

Comment: and sorting by columns works?

Comment: @DanielVaquero nope sorting doesnt work and takes me to a page with refresh. any ajax action is not working it seems in this grid.

Comment: can you show the cgridview in here please. the problem might be how you set it up

Comment: try putting this line at the end of the view file: <?php Yii::app()->getClientScript()->scriptMap=array('jquery.min.js'=>false); ?>

Comment: @DanielVaquero i tried your suggested solution and still it refreshing multiple times..  <?php Yii::app()->getClientScript()->scriptMap=array('jquery.min.js'=>false); ?> Can u pls check the edited section of above question if you dint see it yet. tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just an ideea, try

```
$('#sessions .refreshdata').live('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.fn.yiiGridView({ 'ajaxUpdate':['sessions-grid']  });
);
```

hope this helps

can you show the cgridview in here please. the problem might be how you set it up

Comment: Nope, this doesnt work. Please check the edited section 2 above in the question.

Comment: pls add your cgridview code in the question, i just tryed it at it works just fine your way and mine.